# JavaScript | erroneous result when adding month to date using a variable

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I am trying to add months to a date based on month variable, but I get wrong result when I try to fetch month from an input field and pass it. and I get the correct result if I myself define a variable and pass it to setMonth.

here is the code :

when I use static value :

```
.on('changeDate', function(e){

        var datea = new Date(e.date);
        console.log(datea);
        // var montha = $('#duration').val();
        // console.log(montha);
        montha = 3 ;
         datea.setMonth(datea.getMonth()+ montha);
         datea = datea.getDate() + "/" + datea.getMonth() + "/" + datea.getFullYear();

         console.log(datea);
         $('#end_date').val(datea);

    });
```

console output :

```
Sat Apr 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
1/6/2017
```

as you can see it prints correct output

but If I try fetching the month value from an input field

```
.on('changeDate', function(e){

        var datea = new Date(e.date);
        console.log(datea);
        var montha = $('#duration').val();
        console.log(montha);

         datea.setMonth(datea.getMonth()+ montha);
         datea = datea.getDate() + "/" + datea.getMonth() + "/" + datea.getFullYear();

         console.log(datea);
         $('#end_date').val(datea);

    });
```

Console output :

```
Sat Apr 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
3
1/9/2019
```

even though the montha has value 3 the output result is not correct.

Please help me solve this

Comment: 1) If you're going to go to so much trouble to include the code, why not post an actual example of a snippet that others can use?  You'll get answers much faster.  2) Why do you use `o/p` everywhere instead of just typing "output"  you saved 3 letters but created 1000x more confusion.  Clearer questions = faster responses.

Comment: @vol7ron my bad about the o/p. I will edit the post but the actual code sipped was too long and unnecessary with respect to the issue at hand. That is why I chose to post only a part of the code.

Comment: Yes you just went to effort to copy it in, just explaining that the snippets are easier to demonstrate and work with.  Anyhow, welcome back to SO and good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a check in my browser console, and I think the issue may cause by the input value was not casting to number type. From the below picture, the date1 is adding 3 (number type) to setMonth function, then get the correct date "2017/7/...". However, the date2 is adding '3'(string type) to setMonth function then get date "2019/10/...".

[image]

Comment: That answers the *why*, and the solution is…?

Comment: Your answer is right and I solved it by parsing the variable with parseInt() and then passed it to setMonth and everything worked fine.